# Ruby On Rails how to check if a scaffold has at least one entry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scaffold

I just started with rails and follow this rails course: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fmyvWz5TUWg

```
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <% if user_signed_in? %>
          <% if @friends.one? %>
            <th><strong>First name</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Last name</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Email</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Phone</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Instagram</strong></th>
            <th style="border: none;"></th>
            <th style="border: none;"></th>
            <th style="border-left: none;"></th>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
    </thead>
```

This is the code I have right now. It's a friends list. I want to only show the table once the user has at least one friend added in the scaffold using devise gem.

I googled about this already and found out about the "@friends.one?" but it doesn't seem to work.

I hope I gave all the important information and used the right terms for explanation. Feel free to correct me.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: hi can you try this <% @friends.count > 1 %> instead of <% @friends.one? %>

Answer (score 1):

[`one?`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-one-3F) returns only `true` when there is *exactly one record* in the list.

In your case, it looks like you want to show table headers if there are *any records* in the list. Just use [`any?`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-any-3F) instead of `one?`.